# Can I enable USB debugging and recover data via PC from a phone with broken touch?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-debugging

One of the possibilities is attaching a mouse via an OTG adapter and enable USB debug from there. Or just replace the touch screen, of course.

At the moment, I don’t have an OTG adapter and the cost of replacing the screen surpasses the phones price.

So I am left wondering, is there any other way?

Comment: Is your data deleted or corrupted? If not, you may be able to simply to copy the data off the device in MTP mode.

Comment: If the screen itself is still working you could do so theoretically. The main problem is that if you have  enabled ABD and connect the phone to your PC a dialog comes up and asks if you allow adb access form the currently connected PC. This dialog disappears if you disconnect the PC (e.g. because you want to connect the mouse via OTG). Therefore you may need to (temporary) use a Android remote control software like  TeamViewer, AirDroid, ...

Comment: there is another way (for some ancient devices) https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bypass-secure-usb-debugging-prompt-on-phone-with-broken-screen.2965462/post-76618122